# Android: Showing indeterminate progress bar in TabHost activity

Tags: java, android

I know that the following code should show and hide a tiny circular progress bar with the following code in Android:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

The problem is that I am using a TabHost and I need to be able to do this from one of the "child" activities. Is there any way I can go about doing this?

I found [this question](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg18609.html) on the intarwebs but as you can see, it went unanswered.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

And I found the answer. In your parent activity, before you do **anything**, you need to do the requestWindowFeature call, and then in your child activity you call `getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true/false);`

Comment: Thanks -- this is a really useful and unobtrusive way to show the usre that something is happening.

Answer (score 9):

### Just for completeness:

If the task is running in a different thread other than Main ui thread, you can do:

```
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(mToggleIndeterminate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good point!  This is a subtlety that should not be overlooked.